# Как сделать порядок элементов в словаре - не изменяемым

Tags: python

В мой словарь - через цикл заносятся элементы, которые обработал поисковик,

`list = [(obj_url,obj_name),(obj_url1,obj_name1)]` , но в таком виде они не остаются, при выполнении другого запроса(И обновлении страницы, с уже другим адресом) срабатывает эвент и поисковик, меняет  порядок элементов в нем.

И объект `(obj_url1,obj_name1)`, становиться с 1 индекса на 0, а предыдущий объект с 0 на 1, т.е obj_url1 выходит вперед, даже если это не нужно.

Влазить в метод обработки данных - поисковиком, не имеет особого смысла, по этому хотел бы узнать - как правильно следует пресечь  подобный глюк поисковика.

Чтобы после того как все объекты , к примеру book/T-Shirt  добавятся в простой словарик list [], они больше не как не обрабатывались ?

Код:

---

```
for field_value in self.facet_counts:
    if closed == False:
        datum.append(field_value)
        if  self.facet_counts.index(field_value) == 1:
            closed = True
print datum
```

пояснение

---

`self.facet_counts` = это данные которые обработал поисковик, `[u'Book', u'T-shirt']`

`if  self.facet_counts.index(field_value) == 1:` 
Это что то типо моей провеки(если последний элемент обработан, то добавление закрываем) =) но она обречена на  fail(поскольку я проверяю входящие данные, а не те что добавились),ибо мне ближе синтаксис C++ , и там бы это сработало =) , но питон.... , объясните как следует ?
.

Comment: `map` не предназначен для хранения упорядоченной последовательности пар, он предназначен для _отображения_ ключа в значение. Если я правильно помню, Python _специально_ меняет порядок, чтобы вы не полагались на него. Если вам нужно сохранение порядка, либо сортируйте ключи вручную, либо используйте более подходящую для вас структуру данных.

Comment: @VladD Я с этим уже столько промучился, что буду рад любому рабочему решению... =) только бы в коде увидеть.

Comment: @Vladd не могли бы привести пример, сортировки ключей в ручную, конкретно для моей задачи как это будет выглядеть ? Ибо как я понял данные в словаре попросту не остаются(если сделать ограничение), при обновлении страницы(С уже другим адресом). P.S. Как то сложно к этому привыкнуть когда работаешь еще в C++, где как раз все остается в памяти.

Comment: К сожалению, не смогу, я не работал никогда с Питоном.

Comment: вы понимаете что `[]` это список, а не словарь в Питоне? Если вам ближе C++, то у вас `vector<>`, а не `unordered_map<>`. Это уже упорядоченная структура данных. Проблема у вас в коде, который не показан. Выглядит это как [XY-проблема](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795/23044)

Comment: @jfs Я вам показал тот код который я использую, код поисковика я достать не могу, да и изменять я думаю это не следует . Я понимаю что такое список list и словарь dict, на сколько я понял то что данные не остаются в памяти это специфика языка Python, я к примеру заполнил объекты `T-Shirt,Book` в заголовке `/ru/catalogue/` - сайта, а потом выбрал T-Shirt, ?`selected_facets=T-shirt` И тем самым я перешел на другую страницу, и данные в том списке уже пустые(поскольку я сделал ограничение if url == selected чтобы новый запрос(в другом порядке) не добавлялся ), т.к. старое оно не сохраняет.

Comment: *"данные не остаются в памяти это специфика Питона"* —это неверно мягко говоря. Если вы понимаете что такое список, а что словарь, то почему список назван словарём: `search_dict`? (`dict` это название типа словаря в Питоне—от слова dictionary) Если вы не можете изменить код, который генерирует этот **список**, то порядок вы не сохраните, если не начнёте явно его хранить сами. Хотя лучше если вы изложите действительную вашу задачу, а не неудачную попытку её решения.

Comment: @jfs задача связана с сайтовым движком django(написанным на питоне), и упирается в то что при каждом запросе - на новый url, класс который обрабатывает этот url - обнуляется, тем самым я не могу понять что в нем было ранее. А это мне необходимо чтобы подстраивать результат - багнутой обработки данных(поисковиком) - корректным образом( ибо поисковик меняет порядок) Без выбора http://i.imgur.com/EaDcc9V.png?2 url = ru/catalouge, и с выбором http://i.imgur.com/ObfzssL.png?1 url = ru/catalouge=selected_facets=Common .

Comment: Если у вас вопрос про django, то и спрашивайте про django. Создайте [mcve] и опубликуйте в виде отдельного вопроса.

Comment: @jfs Джанго написан на питоне, но по этому тегу мало народу просматривает вопросы - я уже пробовал . В общем тут только самому решать....

Comment: @LighFusion вы понимаете что текущий ваш вопрос никак не поможет вам с сайтом? На заголовок вам уже дали ответ: OrderedDict —это правильный ответ, если хотите в словаре упорядочено ключи хранить—это никак не поможет изменить порядок вашего списка (с вводящим в заблуждение именем search_dict).

Comment: @jfs Теперь то да я понимаю, ибо в питоне я не так шарю как в C++ , я думал что класс - не влияет на содержание, а как оказалось влияет, ибо тот же самый OrderedDict обнуляется при каждом обращении к классу(через GET Запрос, который обновляет HTML).

Comment: @jfs - в общем да вы были правы! ивправду пришлось изменить саму структуру поисковика - закоментил вот это            #`if value:
                sqs = sqs.narrow(u'%s:"%s"' % (field, sqs.query.clean(value)))` и проблема решилась !!! Только я не пойму что это и для чего служит =) полный код http://pastebin.com/pjeHm5i5 !!Блин наконец то целую неделю мучался !! ужс !! спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Python есть такая структура - [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

> Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they remember the order that items were inserted. When iterating over an ordered dictionary, the items are returned in the order their keys were first added.

```
>>> import collections
>>> a = collections.OrderedDict()
>>> a['w'] = {}
>>> a['a'] = {}
>>> a['s'] = {}
>>> a
OrderedDict([('w', {}), ('a', {}), ('s', {})])

>>> dict(a)
{'a': {}, 's': {}, 'w': {}}
```

Comment: Это по-моему немного не то, поскольку я не могу менять сам метод поиска, проблема в том что элементы продолжают добавляться в словарь.Т.е без срабатывания метода было `[u T-shirt', u Book]` , потом метод сработал и данные передались уже другие `[Book, u T-shirt]`, т.е append(присвоить) не прекращает своей работы, даже если в словаре все нужные элементы занесены.

Comment: хотя да получается что нужно менять структуру поисковика ! Он ее менял, зачем то =) ужс ! и спасиб!